# What is the naming convention for a re-exporter?

Tags: rust, module

I would like to structure my code so that an experienced Rust developer would not be confused when attempting to join my project.

Currently, I have a directory hierarchy that looks like this:

```
main.rs
types/
-types_pt1.rs
-types_pt2.rs
-re_exporter.rs
```

And `re_exporter.rs` looks like this:

```
pub mod types_pt1;
pub mod types_pt2;
```

Finally, `main.rs` looks like this:

```
#[path = "types/re_exporter.rs"]
mod re_exporter;

use crate::re_exporter::{types_pt1, types_pt2};
```

What is the convention for naming `re_exporter.rs`?

Comment: mod.rs, that is the name for a module. Or put it as a brother of `main.rs` and call it `types.rs`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The naming convention most used is the one that Rust detects by default, that is rename your module `mod types;`, remove the `#[path = "types/re_exporter.rs"]` and put the code in either `src/types.rs` or `src/types/mod.rs`.